# does the newline have a special meaning in sqlLite? i got missing database (near "SELECT": syntax error)

Tags: sqlite, newline

If I remove the newline, I suddenly get an error.

**missing database (near "SELECT": syntax error)**

without new line it doesn't work from with sqlite - bug or not? Ot a problem with Jetbrains IDE?

if i make the select shorter i have also no error anymore.

### this select gives the error:

> SELECT * FROM ( SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement FROM Words WHERE wordindexed LIKE 'gt%' and ActionListID = 1 order by ROWID asc LIMIT 10 ) t2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ( SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement FROM Words WHERE wordindexed GLOB '%gt%' and ActionListID = 1 order by ROWID desc LIMIT 10 ) t3 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ( SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement FROM Words WHERE wordindexed like '%gt%' and ActionListID = 1 LIMIT 2 ) t4 SELECT * FROM ( SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement FROM Words WHERE wordindexed like 'gt%' LIMIT 2 ) t5 SELECT * FROM ( SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement FROM Words WHERE wordindexed like '%gt%' LIMIT 2 ) t6 limit 10;

the same with all new lines and it has no error:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement
     FROM Words
     WHERE wordindexed LIKE 's%'
     and   ActionListID > 0
     order by ROWID asc
     LIMIT 10
     ) t2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
...
```

Sorry I had to put it outside because this web-GUI surface did not allow otherwise. https://gist.github.com/sl5net/731c5ef0cd7c68dbddc86bc26cc5838f

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### i am using:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b19 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 0):

After the `T4` and `t5` sub-selects, you are missing the `UNION ALL`.

Also there is no need to use sub-selects for the UNION. You can use those directly instead of the `SELECT * FROM`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement
    FROM Words
    WHERE wordindexed LIKE 'gt%' and ActionListID = 1
    order by ROWID asc
    LIMIT 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement
    FROM Words
    WHERE wordindexed GLOB '%gt%' and ActionListID = 1
    order by ROWID desc
    LIMIT 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement
    FROM Words
    WHERE wordindexed like '%gt%' and ActionListID = 1
    LIMIT 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement
    FROM Words
    WHERE wordindexed like 'gt%'
    LIMIT 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT distinct word, worddescription, wordreplacement
    FROM Words
    WHERE wordindexed like '%gt%' LIMIT 2
) limit 10;
```

Instead, use a SELECT enclosing all the union selects to perform the last `limit 10`.

Comment: i used join subselect unique without using distinct becouse of performance reasons. maybe its more performance. therfore ASC and DESC. But way the select above works perfect with newlines? and not without? thats confusing me.

Comment: No. the point was that you dropped two "UNION ALL". No only newlines. Note that "UNION" instead of "UNION ALL" also makes a "DISTINCT". However, the "DISTINCT" also influences the "LIMIT n".